# How to conditionally add a class to a Magnolia component template based on the presence of another Component?

Tags: freemarker, magnolia

I would like to apply a class to my title component in Magnolia only if the content editors have chosen to add the subtitle component to a page. Example of what I am trying to do below:

```
[#assign subtitle = "somehow get a reference to the subtitle component"]
[#assign subtitleExists = subtitle?has_content]
<div class="title ${subtitleExists?then('removePadding','')}">
  ${model.render('titleCopy')!}
</div>
```

Is this possible? I am happy to add more information to help clarify what I am trying to do here if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Components are atomic, hence they normally don't see each other and can't influence each other. That would be job of the area grouping the components or parent component or the page itself.

That said, if the structure of the page and of your templates doesn't allow you any other solution, you might set some flag via request attribute in subtitle component and then check for the existence of said flag in your component.
Something along the lines of `ctx.setAttribute("subtitleExists", true, 1)` on one side and `ctx.getAttribute("subtitleExists")` on the other side. 1 stands for the local (request) scope for the attribute.